# How long and how often should I water my concrete?

Tags: water, cement

I have just applied cement on some stone joints, and I was wondering for how long should I pour water on it? How frequently should I apply water? Is it twice a day, or thrice a day? I really need to avoid cracks and weak joints.

Answer (score 2):

Best is to keep it damp "forever." Design strength for most concrete is based  on 28 days at 21C/70F. The early part of the cure is the most critical. Time is doubled at 50F/10C and reduced at higher temperatures - so long as it's kept damp.

Covering with damp cloths/burlap/sacking and then covering that with plastic can help to keep it damp longer (from a single application of water.) Just covering with plastic helps some. How frequently you need to apply water will vary with climate and how much you have done to keep the water in place.

Answer (score 1):

Procedure which Ecnerwal
has explained is "by the book" and I agree 100% if we would be speaking about concrete slab, wall etc. But since you are just using cement for joints in a stone wall no need to pure water over it.In fact, you could cause damage if you would pour water because there is a chance that cement would wash of. My advice would be just to use "heavy duty" cement plaster for this

Comment: Masonry is masonry - it all works the same way, more or less. If you pour on water before the initial set has taken place, you will wash away; if you pour it on after the initial set has taken place, it won't wash (unless you "pour it on" by spraying with a high-pressure hose in the first few days.) A proper cure is essential to the strength of any masonry product.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I don't know if you are from building industry, but have never seen, or heard of  that someone is watering masonry joints, not when you building brick wall, stone wall or any other. With concrete you must water it, especially if temperature is high, but not during winter if there is a possibility of freezing temperature.

Comment: So for a wall made of bricks and cement what do you suggest? In a hot country. 35 degress centigrade

Comment: Nothing special you do it like everywhere. I was thinking about this subject and I think I know what might have cause confusion. When you are building a wall sometimes people soak the bricks into the bucket of water for a few seconds before they place them in the wall over a layer of mortar. People do it in order to "fill" the bricks with water so they wouldn't soak the water from mortar. Generally, you can check your wall for cracks in mortar for a first few days and if you spot cracks in mortar I guess you can spray it  with water since it so hot, but like I said no one waters the walls.

Answer (score 0):

After pouring the concrete slab, we will keep the water in concrete for 48 hours. After 48 hours we must start watering the concrete to maintain it, because the chemical actions still need watering. We continue watering the slab for at least 5 days.